# Plotly - How to remove the rangeslider

Tags: javascript, python, plotly

By default, candlestick and ohlc charts display a rangeslider.

It seems like there's no parameter to change the setting. So I've looked at javascript code in html file but was not able to find a clue to remove it.

Can someone explain how to remove the rangeslider from candlestick chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution..

Following code hides the rangeslider graph on the bottom of candle stick chart..

xaxis : {fixedrange: true, rangeslider: {visible: false}}